# como poner que una opción seleccionada de un menú quede marcada .current en bootstrap?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

En un menú navbar de bootstrap. ¿como poner la opción marcada? que clase usar?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- El logotipo y el icono que despliega el menú se agrupan
       para mostrarlos mejor en los dispositivos móviles -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Desplegar navegación</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

  </div>

  <!-- Agrupar los enlaces de navegación, los formularios y cualquier
       otro elemento que se pueda ocultar al minimizar la barra -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="linkmenu"><a href="index.php">Biografía</a></li>
      <li class="linkmenu"><a href="discografia.php">Discografía</a></li>
      <li class="linkmenu"><a href="videos.php">Videos</a></li>
      <li class="linkmenu"><a href="descargas.php">Descargas</a></li>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con una clase `.activa` puedes conseguir este efecto, pero tendrás que añadir un poquito de jQuery para realizar la transición automáticamente:

Al hacer click sobre un enlace del menú, este se marcará como activo y el antiguo enlace con esta propiedad se desmarcará.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".nav li").on("click", function(){
    $(".nav").find(".activa").removeClass("activa");
    $(this).addClass("activa");
  });
});
```

```css
/*CSS*/
.activa{
 background-color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- El logotipo y el icono que despliega el menú se agrupan
         para mostrarlos mejor en los dispositivos móviles -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Desplegar navegación</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>

    <!-- Agrupar los enlaces de navegación, los formularios y cualquier
         otro elemento que se pueda ocultar al minimizar la barra -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="linkmenu"><a href="#">Biografía</a></li>
        <li class="linkmenu"><a href="#">Discografía</a></li>
        <li class="linkmenu"><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
        <li class="linkmenu"><a href="#">Descargas</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Y por útlimo remarcar que tengas cuidado al cerrar tus etiquetas HTML ya que el elemento `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` no lo tienes cerrado en tu código.

Espero que te sirva, un saludo.

Comment: he añadido tu codigo js a bootstrap.js y en style.css he añadido nav.navbar li a.active 
{
 color:#658955;

}  pero no me funciona

Comment: @Rafahernandez No lo había probado porque no estaba en mi ordenador, actualizo la respuesta habiéndolo probado y verificando que funciona correctamente. Te recomiendo que los cambios no los añadas a los archivos originales de bootstrap, créate un fichero css y otro js para tu código y añádelos en el head al igual que añades los ficheros de bootstrap, pero procura no mezclarlos salvo que sea completamente necesario.

Comment: ya he hecho lo que dices he creado un archivo .js para el javascript. en mi style.css he puesto .active.... pero ese estilo se aplica a las migas de pan no al menu. he probado con nav.navbar .active 
{
   background-color:lightblue;

} pero no consigo que el .active se aplique al menú.

Comment: @Rafahernandez He actualizado mi respuesta con un ejemplo ejecutable funcionando correctamente. Revisa que tus archivos (tanto css como js) estén bien enlazados y que no tengas ningún error de sintaxis.

Comment: No consigo hacerlo funcionar. he cerrado el </ul> he comprobado que se carge el script jquery que me has pasado. en el style.css he puesto .activa{....} pero no me funciona

Comment: @Rafahernandez Presiona f12 en el navegador que estés ejecutando tu aplicación web, ahí verás una pestaña llamada Console, ¿Te muestra algún error?

Comment: En la consola no hay ningun error relacionado con el css de .activa